# Using sed command search for a word and substitute the next word

Tags: bash, sed

I have a big file which has the word TITLE and the near word the name . So, for example :

```
cat file1 :

NAME('SAM') SURNAME('WILLIAMS') PASWD('SAMWIL') TITLE('QA')
NAME('JOHN') SURNAME('ROGERS') PASWD('ROGJH') TITLE('QA')
NAME('MATT') SURNAME('JERRY') GRP('ONE') TITLE('RN') PASWD('JERMAT')
NAME('TEST2') SURNAME('NAZ') GRP('TWO') AUTH(USE) TITLE('DEV') GRP('ONE')
```

I am trying to substitute all TITLE(...) to TITLE('DEV') . So, the output should be :

```
cat file1 :

NAME('SAM') SURNAME('WILLIAMS') PASWD('SAMWIL') TITLE('DEV')
NAME('JOHN') SURNAME('ROGERS') PASWD('ROGJH') TITLE('DEV')
NAME('MATT') SURNAME('JERRY') GRP('ONE') TITLE('DEV') PASWD('JERMAT')
NAME('TEST2') SURNAME('NAZ') GRP('TWO') AUTH(USE) TITLE('DEV') GRP('ONE')
```

I just used sed to grep the TITLE and everything after :

```
sed 's/.*\(TITLE...\)/\1/' file1
```

Not sure how to substitute the TITLE part . 
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For given format, this would do:

```
sed -e "s#\(TITLE('\)[^']\+')#\1DEV')#" file1
```

Actually This may be a bit easier to parse:

```
sed -e "s#\<TITLE('[^']\+')\>#TITLE('DEV')#" file1
```

And we do not really save ourselves that much typing with the back reference.

You find any instance of `TITLE('<CHARS_NOT_APOSTROPHE>')` (I've also added word edges for a good measure.) and replaces it with `TITLE('DEV')`.

Answer (score 3):

If your example input file is representative of all your possible inputs, then the following is possibly the shortest and still readable solution you can get:

```
sed "s/TITLE([^)]*)/TITLE('DEV')/" file1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed --expression="s/TITLE('[^']*')/TITLE('DEV')/" file1
```

Let me know if you need an explanation of the above RegExp.

Comment: Thank you for the command. It works perfectly. If you provide explanation, I would really appreciate that ! I have never used sed --expression command .

Comment: `sed --expression="..."` is the same as `sed -e "..."`. It's just more 'formal' and that's why I prefer it over a shorter option variant.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
$ cat titles.dat
NAME('SAM') SURNAME('WILLIAMS') PASWD('SAMWIL') TITLE('QA')
NAME('JOHN') SURNAME('ROGERS') PASWD('ROGJH') TITLE('QA')
NAME('MATT') SURNAME('JERRY') GRP('ONE') TITLE('RN') PASWD('JERMAT')
NAME('TEST2') SURNAME('NAZ') GRP('TWO') AUTH(USE) TITLE('DEV') GRP('ONE')
```

One `sed` solution:

```
$ sed "s/\(TITLE('\)[^']*\(')\)/\1DEV\2/g" titles.dat
NAME('SAM') SURNAME('WILLIAMS') PASWD('SAMWIL') TITLE('DEV')
NAME('JOHN') SURNAME('ROGERS') PASWD('ROGJH') TITLE('DEV')
NAME('MATT') SURNAME('JERRY') GRP('ONE') TITLE('DEV') PASWD('JERMAT')
NAME('TEST2') SURNAME('NAZ') GRP('TWO') AUTH(USE) TITLE('DEV') GRP('ONE')
```

Where:

- `\(TITLE('\)` - find our first pattern `TITLE('`; store as pattern #1
- `[^']*` - match on everything after pattern #1 as long as not a single quote (')
- `\(')\)` - find our second pattern `')`; store as pattern #2
- `\1DDEV\2` - output pattern #1 + 'DEV' + pattern #2